# Where clause in fusion table query with google map javascript api v3

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I want to put a fusion table layer over my google map using javascript api v3. There are four columns in it: iso, color, name, geometry. My fusion table is:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1uO0anbhABVwjktSOy-PJsGo0Q4y-gTtzAe607c8

Why I can filter with: `where: 'color=0'`
but cannot filter with: `where: 'iso="AU"'`

'color' column type is number and 'iso' column type is text.

Any syntax error in that query? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I find out why.

The  where clause should be changed to `where: "iso='AU'"`.
Double quotes should surround single quotes.